# prove the linear combination of variables smaller than zero given the linear combination of their upper bound and lower bound smaller than zero

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry

I'd like to prove that

$a^Tx \leq 0$, where $x$ is a vector with all entries $x_i\geq 0$, given that

$a^Ty\leq 0$ and $a^Tz\leq 0$,

where $0\leq y_i\leq x_i\leq z_i$ for all $i$.

I can only show that $x\in \{x=c_1y+c_2z,\forall c_1,c_2\geq 0\}$ gives $a^Tx \leq 0$, which is trivial. It seems not all $x$ satisfying $y_i\leq x_i\leq z_i$ lead to the conclusion.

Many thanks!

Comment: Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: @5xum sure, have done it accordingly.

Comment: You know, once you get an answer to the question, it's nice to either accept it or explain why it is not what you need...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can prove what you want to prove.

Take 
$$
\begin{align}
a&=\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\end{bmatrix}\\
y&=\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\end{bmatrix}\\
z&=\begin{bmatrix}5\\6\end{bmatrix}\\
x&=\begin{bmatrix}4\\3\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
$$

Then:

- $a^Ty=1-2=-1\leq 0$
- $a^Tz=5-6=-1\leq 0$
- $0\leq 1=y_1\leq 4=x_1\leq 5=z_1$ and $0\leq 2=y_2\leq3=x_2\leq6=z_2$

So all conditions are satisfied, however $a^Tx=4-3=1>0$, so $a,x,y,z$ form a counterexample.